# Why nestjs unit tests create testing module in beforeEach instead of beforeAll?

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

In the nestjs, the test file (template from the cli) have the `Test.createTestingModule` inside `beforeEach`, so it recreates the module before every test.

e.g. foo.service.spec.ts

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { FooService } from './foo.service';

describe('FooService', () => {
  let service: FooService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [FooService],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<FooService>(FooService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

But why is it in the `beforeEach` and not in `beforeAll`?

Is there any reason for it to be in `beforeEach`? Maybe it will cause problems?

I saw that in the e2e tests, the application is created in `beforeAll`, so I'm not sure why the unit test is created in `beforeEach`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you usually need to create mocks and spies when you want to  perform unit tests which is not true in E2E tests where you want real database connections, ...etc.

If you define your module in BeforeAll then you need to create AfterEach to clear history of each of your spies and mocks.

Also because everything in E2E is real, It really takes long time if we would re-initialize all modules and connections for each tests.